# Postman - How can I compare a message using vars

Tags: postman

can anyone help me, I am almost new in Postman.

my issue is as follow:

- I send a POST request and get a message asresponse:

  {
      "errorCode": 1000,
      "errorDescription": "Account is not verified by Admin!"
  }
- this message is already saved in a var named "**messageAccountIsnotVerified**"
- when I try to use comparison in postman tets script and compare the message with the expected string is working fine:

> ```
> pm.test("test", function () {
>     var jsonData = pm.response.json();
>     pm.expect(jsonData.errorCode).to.eql(1000);
>     pm.expect(jsonData.errorDescription).to.eql("Account is not verified by Admin!");
> });
> ```

But When I try to save the String text *"Account is not verified by Admin!"* in a variable named: **messageAccountIsnotVerified**
and try to make the same comparison

```
pm.test("test", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();

    pm.expect(jsonData.errorCode).to.eql(1000);
    pm.expect(jsonData.errorDescription).to.eql("messageAccountIsnotVerified");
});
```

or

```
pm.test("test", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    var message = pm.environment.get("messageAccountIsnotVerified");
    pm.expect(jsonData.errorCode).to.eql(1000);
    pm.expect(jsonData.errorDescription).to.eql(message);
});
```

it **failed** with **error**:

```
test | AssertionError: expected 'Account is not verified by Admin!' to deeply equal 'messageAccountIsnotVerified'
```

Can someone explain to me 
1. what does the "deeply equal" mean and 
2. what do I wrong and 
3. how can I use the assertion by using the variable

Thanks for any Hint

> Just additional Info: I have the same issue when I compare email with
>   @ sign in another message - so I assume may be something to do with special chars

Comment: For clarity, could you post the actual response body returned?

Comment: response body was:
{
    "errorCode": 1000,
    "errorDescription": "Account is not verified by Admin!"
}

Comment: If that is the case, then there is no reason way the first test shouldn't just work. Is the response exactly like the Postman image in my answer? No additional character anywhere?

Comment: ok, I can see what you've done now. You save the entire message as the environment variable. I get why it would return that message now. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get the variable in the following way:

```
pm.expect(jsonData.errorDescription).to.deep.equal(pm.environment.get("messageAccountIsnotVerified"))
```

`.to.deep.equal` can be used to reference something further down in a nested object.

> Add .deep earlier in the chain to use deep equality instead. See the deep-eql project page for info on the deep equality algorithm: https://github.com/chaijs/deep-eql.

Looking at the response body you posted `{ "errorCode": 1000, "errorDescription": "Account is not verified by Admin!" }`, I don't see a problem with the first test but for it to complain about `deep equal` then this response is probably no exactly as you posted.

[image: Postman]

You could reduce this all down again if you wanted too:

```
pm.test("test", () => {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json()).to.deep.equal({"errorCode": 1000, "errorDescription": "Account is not verified by Admin!"})
});
```

That test would do the same as above.

Comment: Many Thanks it works with your solution:
pm.expect(jsonData.errorDescription).to.deep.equal(pm.environment.get("messageAccountIsnotVerified"))


just to answer your last question:
**response body was:**
{
    "errorCode": 1000,
    "errorDescription": "Account is not verified by Admin!"
}

but with solution mentioned is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

let string = pm.response.json()

pm.expect(string).to.equal("String from Response")